# Querying One-To-Many Relationships in Django and then aggregate

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am learning Django on a peculiar project whereby I am tracking football/soccer player statistics to view in a bootstrap Dashboard. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I am able to loop over each player, I am also able to loop over their history (separate model) but I am unable to group each player to their history and display on one page while doing other calculations. I am also unable to group players by their club or category.

There are 3 models: Players, Category, Club, Timestamp. Each unique player has a one-to-many relationship with Category, Club, and Timestamp. Each player will eventually have millions of timestamps which will act as a history for the player's performance (score, value, etc).

I'd like to easily work out things like:

- Did the player X score increase compare to 24hr/7 days/30 days ago?
- List all players and their timestamps from category (or team) X.
- What is the total score of each player in category X (based from the latest timestamp record)

I've started with = Player.objects.all() or Timestamp.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp') but I am unsure how to do set this up so that I can do the above, within one view.

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    player_position = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # category_updated

    # category_updated_date = models.DateTimeField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.player_name


class Timestamp(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    buy_now = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    sell_now = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    last_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

EDITS - What I have tried so far:

I have created a function-based view, which returns all players in a category and then totals up the last timestamp value for each of those players.

While this works to create a total of that entire category's latest price, I'm not certain this is the correct way to achieve this.

```
def category_detail(request, cat):

    catID = Category.objects.get(id=cat)

    page_title = f"{catID.name}"

    players = Player.objects.filter(category=cat)

    total_buy = 0

    for player in players:

        x = player.timestamp_set.last()

        total_buy += x.buy_now

    return render(request, "dashboard/category_detail.html", locals())
```

To check whether the player's score has changed over x days, I have tried to put in the below line but this only compares against the first and last. I'd like to compare against the last and then 24 hours, 7 Days, 1 month etc.

```
<td>{% if item.timestamp_set.last.score > item.timestamp_set.first.score %}UP{% else %}DOWN{% endif %}</td>
```

Comment: Can you write what you have in your view so far? Also, what have you tried for the three tasks?

Comment: Sorry, I have now edited the original post with what I have tried.